# Device ID recognition

Tags: android, iphone, udid

I have a web and mobile application which offers waiting list management to businesses and their respective customers. Currently in the mobile application, customers fill out a profile form and save it locally on their devices (iPhone and Android). Then they can individually Check-In to a selected business. When they click the Check-In button, their device ID gets appended with the profile information and sent to the web app. In turn, the business' employees can save them in their database and send them push notifications.

What I want to do is allow those push notifications to be sent when the employee manually adds a customer's name and phone number, but does not have the device ID. This way, the mobile app user won't have to initiate the contact each time by submitting their profile info and device ID.

Any and all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2853253/739270

Answer (score 0):

In iPhone you can get the device UDID, Using following code;

```
-(NSString*)getDeviceUDID{
    if ([Mode isEqualToString:@"Device"]) {
        NSString *domain = @"com.CompanyName.AppName";// You can specify any Domain here
        NSString *key = @"CityName";// You can specify any key here
        NSString *UDID = [SecureUDID UDIDForDomain:domain usingKey:key];
        return UDID;
    }else{
        NSString* UDID=[[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
        UDID=[UDID substringToIndex:32];
        return UDID;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.